# Why do I get "TimeoutHandler Expiring message ID" Warnings

Tags: jms, wso2-esb

I have several proxies (passing messages using JMS) and I guess there is somewhere a proxy that is always generating WARNINGS into my `wso2carbon.log` file:

```
WARN {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender} -  Did not receive a JMS response within 30000 ms to destination : temp-queue://ID:EAI-P01-59160-1365080800632-57287:1:1 with JMS correlation ID : ID:EAI-P01-59160-1365080800632-57285:1:1:1:1 {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSSender}
WARN {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler} -  Expiring message ID : urn:uuid:5428da0b-8f52-49ea-bcff-66df02a54daf; dropping message after global timeout of : 120 seconds {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.TimeoutHandler}
```

Why do I get these warnings, I always specify the property `<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>`.

Unfortunately I cannot really reproduce it, but maybe someone knows why this is happening (send to JMS?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searched so long and I just forgot to set `<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>` in one proxy sending to JMS.

I leave the question here - so maybe someone looks for that information.